What to do with a seemingly AI-generated answer?
This newly added answer to a 5-year-old question came up in the Late Answers queue for review. Its format and language look suspiciously ChatGPT-like (see details below). What should we do in such cases? The options are:


To obtain evidence confirming my suspicion I tried posting the same question on ChatGPT and got:

I further asked if it had written the answer linked above (I copied and pasted it to the chat), and the reply was:


Looks like this site hasn't had discussion related to GenAI. There's a generic help article What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools? as an implementation of Proposed changes to Help Center articles to include mention of AI-generated content policy.

@AndrewT.  Thanks!
